# How to set tickCount of labels in BarSeries xAxis when appended in Qt QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtcharts

I have a BarChart which gets filled by a Button-onClick with Values from a C++ function.
Everything is fine, but there are too much values for the width of my panel. The data contains time-series data in this format:

| Date | Value from 0-1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 0.55 |
| 2021-01-02 | 0.35 |
| 2021-01-03 | 0.77 |
| 2021-01-04 | 0.97 |

When there is to much data, the labels on the x-axis do not get displayed accordingly. I want to show only 3-4 labels.

In a LineSeries, which I used before, I could easily control the amount of labels by defining **tickCount** in **DateTimeAxis**.

How to do it in a Barchart? The data is inserted by **BarSeries.append()**

```
ChartView {
    id: totalChecksChart

    BarSeries {
        id: barChart

        axisX: BarCategoryAxis { 
             categories: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
        }

        BarSet {
            values: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }
    }
}

Button{
    id: refreshButton
    onClicked: {

        _frontPageModel.loadAvailability(_db);
        _frontPageModel.loadDateList(_db);

        graphData = _frontPageModel.getAvailability();

        var dateData = _frontPageModel.getDateList();
        var xAxis = [];
        var yAxis = [];
        for (let f=0; f<dateData.length; f++) {
            xAxis.push(dateData[f]);
        }
        for (let k=0; k<graphData.length; k++) {
            yAxis.push(graphData[k]);
        }

        barChart.clear();
        barChart.axisX.categories = xAxis;
        barChart.axisY.max = 1;
        barChart.axisY.min = 0;

        barChart.append("Verfügbarkeit", yAxis);

    }
}
```